# how to pass json string from Controller to ajax sucess event

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass  "recentlyupgraded"  string   from controller to ajax  success event and check at ajax sucess event .
My code is :

This is My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeEnum(UserRole.Normal, UserRole.Power)]
public ActionResult BusinessUpdate(BusinessSetting business) {
    ActionResult _returns;
    if (viewModel.BusinessSettingUpdate(business)) viewModel.InitalizeBusiness();
    if (Session["recentlyUpgraded"] != null && (bool) Session["recentlyUpgraded"]) {
        _returns = Json("recentlyUpgraded",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    });
} else {
    _returns = PartialView("_Business", viewModel.Business);
}

return _returns;
```

now i  want to check it at ajax  success event   code is:

```
function OnSuccess(formName) {
        $(formName).removeData("validator");
        $(formName).removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formName);
        alert(formName.innerHTML);//this code gives  undefined
 }




 function OnComplete(request, status) {
        $("#DetailandSetting").fadeTo('slow', 1);
     //  alert(JSON.stringify(request));
//        if (request.innerhtml = "recentlyUpgraded") {
//            window.location.href = '/NMPAccount/LogOff';
//        }
    }
```

Note  :This  is ajax form .

Comment: Shouldn't it be `alert($(formName).html())`?

Comment: try ``alert(JSON.stringify(formName))`` to see what is coming

Comment: can please you show your complete ajax request method?

Comment: function OnComplete(request, status) {
        $("#DetailandSetting").fadeTo('slow', 1);
  
    }

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  can you  guide me?

Comment: @govindaghimre, Your controller method makes no sense. The `if` block returns a string and the `else` block returns a partial view (2 different return types). The first 3 lines in the `OnSuccess(formName) {` do nothing (add a `console.log(formName)` to understand), then you try to access the `innerHTML` of a string or a partial view, neither of which exist (a string does not have a property named `innerHTML`). What is it you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In you form:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("TestAction", "TestController")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(model)
})
    .success(function (data) {
        if (data == "USEREXISTS") {
            alert("User exist")
        } else {
            alert("User does not exist")
        }
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert("A java script error occured");
    });
```

In your controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult TestAction(TestViewModel testViewModel)
    {
        // For demonstaration only
        return Json("USEREXISTS", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: in may case ,need to check it  from session  and in ajax form

Comment: @govindaghimre - I am not sure what part you are struggling with? I have provided an example on how to send plain json data from controller and check on view using JQuery.